# NGINX reverse proxy ssl

Tags: ssl, nginx, amazon-ec2, reverse-proxy

Decided to try to configure SSL on my EC2 instance .. it's not going well. Below is my config file for the site I have enabled. What am I doing wrong here? The url upgrades to https but then times out when trying to connect. I have verified the correct proxy_pass IP and port.

```
server {                                                                                
        listen 80;                                                                      

        server_name example.com;                                                         
        location / {                                                                    
                return 404;                                                             
        }                                                                               
}                                                                                       

server {                                                                                
        listen 80;                                                                      
        listen 443 ssl;                                                                 

        server_name my.example.com;                                             

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.example.com/fullchain.pem;     
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.example.com/privkey.pem;   

        location / {                                                                    
                proxy_set_header Host $host;                                            
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;                                
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-for $remote_addr;                          
                proxy_pass http://172.17.0.2:8080;                                      
        }                                                                               

        location /.well-known {                                                         
                root /var/www/html;                                                     
        }                                                                               
}
```

I used letsencrypt.org with certbot to verify and install my certs.

Comment: You didn't allow inbound traffic to TCP port 443 ("HTTPS") in the instance's security group?

Comment: Oh man ... if that&#39;s what I did I&#39;m going to be sad.

Update: It is. 